# How to get used to commonly used packages , classes and interfaces in java?

Tags: java

Hi i am new to java and facing difficulties in learning methods and their parameters , tell me the best way of memorizing all methods,interfaces names etc

Comment: Just get used to Javadoc.

Answer (score 3):

Use an IDE.  Code completion is a wonderful thing.  In eclipse I love to type `syso` ctrl-space and watch `System.out.println()` magically appear.  I love to hover my mouse over a method and have the java docs popup and tell me what it does and what it needs.

Use google.  Use stackoverflow.  Use github.  Use your own code once you've written enough stuff.

Also realize those of us who've been coding for decades still have to look some of this stuff up.  So you're not alone.

It also helps to use cheetsheets:

[image]